# Enabled 'Play DRM' using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, drm, geckodriver

I'm trying to teach myself some python and I've been working on a project which uses selenium to open firefox and interact with netflix but I need to enable 'Play DRM' to stream, I dont see it in 'set_preferences' and I cant inspect element on the contents page in preferences so I'm not sure how to enable it.

```
import time, pyautogui, os
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile = wd.FirefoxProfile()
ntfx='http://www.netflix.com/'
driver=wd.Firefox()
driver.get(ntfx)
url = driver.current_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok looked more into the Firefox Profiles and made a custom profile as show [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). I went into preferences/content and enabled "Play DRM" and added the PATH to the custom profile

```
profile = wd.FirefoxProfile('./fire_fox_profile')
driver=wd.Firefox(profile)
```

Answer (score 3):

Took 4 days but finally came with a solution

```
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.addPreference("media.eme.enabled",true);
        firefoxOptions.addPreference("media.gmp-manager.updateEnabled", true);
```

Then add the *firefoxOptions*  to the driver

Comment: Do you know how to add those "preferences" for the chrome driver?

Answer (score 0):

As alternative solution of using firefox profiles you can do

```py
driver.get('about:preferences')
driver.find_element_by_id('playDRMContent').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of @RonanB worked for me

Just go into about:profiles in firefox
then under the DRM enabled profile, look for the root directory. For me it was : /home/myusername/.mozilla/firefox/14iw27z4.default-release

so like this :

```
myProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/myusername/.mozilla/firefox/14iw27z4.default-release')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(myProfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

First time answering any question on stackoverflow

This little trick worked for me so what i did was

1. First make sure normal firefox(i.e when not launched using selenium or firefox) is able to play [drm video](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/videotag_multiDRM_PlayReadyWidevineFairPlay_notoken.html).
2. Next, i created new firefox profile named 'selenium' and launched firefox with selenium profile.

   To create firefox profile run 'firefox -p' command in windows run program. [picture for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpoqM.png)
3. Now in 'selenium' profile firefox session go to [drm video](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/videotag_multiDRM_PlayReadyWidevineFairPlay_notoken.html) site. Firefox downloaded some drm playing content and after some time drm video played.
4. then i launched firefox with this code:-

   from selenium import webdriver

   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

   profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users{USER}----PATH TO SELENIUM PROFILE FOLDER----")
   print('lll')
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, executable_path=r'-------------\firefox\geckodriver.exe')

   url = 'http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/videotag_multiDRM_PlayReadyWidevineFairPlay_notoken.html'

   driver.get(url)

and my drm video played,
Now this worked for me not sure will work for you
tested on:-

Firefox Version 92.0(64-bit)

gechodriver version geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64